# Android - how to clear accessibility focus

Tags: android, focus, accessibility

I would like to clear accessibility focus. But in my case it is not easy as object that currently has focus is not accessible in the scope, so I cannot call on it clearAccessibilityFocus(). In this moment I request focus on other object, that I have access to and then clear focus, but it is not good solution.
Can you help me with that?

Comment: You can use getCurrentFocus() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus()

Comment: Only description is sufficient to understand your issue and provide solution. Post some code as well.

Comment: posting this part of code = posting about 50 classes, so I would like to avoid this ;) getCurrentFocus unfortunately returns null...

Comment: Clearing accessibility focus from an app is not currently supported, which is why the API is @hidden.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
view.performAccessibilityAction(
            AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLEAR_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null);
```

to clear the accessibility focus.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can go for:

```
myView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call this on view.

```
setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);
```

I was having a problem where accessibility was leaked on the fragment which was added on top of other fragment.
so onCreateView() of the second fragment

```
container.getFocusedChild().setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible situations. If you need to remove focus from real view then you can act like this:

```
view.performAccessibilityAction(
    AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLEAR_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, 
    null
)
```

But if you need to remove focus from virtual view then you should do something like this:

```
view.accessibilityNodeProvider?.performAction(
    virtualViewId,
    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_CLEAR_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS,
    null
)
```